# Jquery and jquery.ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I think is posible change this code to other more simply and efective.

```
$(btn_proy1).click(function(){
$("#btn_Close").fadeIn(100);
$("#ProyectosGrid").hide("explode",1000);
$("#Proy1").fadeIn(100);
});
$(btn_proy2).click(function(){
$("#btn_Close").fadeIn(100);
$("#ProyectosGrid").hide("explode",1000);
$("#Proy2").fadeIn(100);
});
$(btn_proy3).click(function(){
$("#btn_Close").fadeIn(100);
$("#ProyectosGrid").hide("explode",1000);
$("#Proy3").fadeIn(100);
});
$(btn_proy4).click(function(){
$("#btn_Close").fadeIn(100);
$("#ProyectosGrid").hide("explode",1000);
$("#Proy4").fadeIn(100);
});
$(btn_proy5).click(function(){
$("#btn_Close").fadeIn(100);
$("#ProyectosGrid").hide("explode",1000);
$("#Proy5").fadeIn(100);
});

$(btn_Close).click(function(){
$("#btn_Close").fadeOut(100);
$("#ProyectosGrid").show("explode",1000);
$("#Proy5").fadeOut();
$("#Proy4").fadeOut();
$("#Proy3").fadeOut();
$("#Proy2").fadeOut();
$("#Proy1").fadeOut();
});
```

All the function are similars but the ID's are diferent, if is posible sent an argument in the code when call it. For example:

```
$(btn_clicked).click(function(){
 $("#btn_Close").fadeIn(100);
 $("#ProyectosGrid").hide("explode",1000);
 $("#Proy_clicked").fadeIn(100);
});
$(btn_Close).click(function(){
 $("#btn_Close").fadeOut(100);
 $("proyectosGrid").show("explode",1000);
 $("proyActive").fadeOut();
)};
```

So... i dont have any idea how make it works u.u

Comment: add common class and use this common class as a jquery selector so write your code once

Comment: @downvoter: OP is newcomer , so do comment why you downvoted, good to guide ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class for your buttons and then select all button at once.

```
$(".btnClass").click(function(event){   
   $("#btn_Close").fadeIn(100);  
   $("#ProyectosGrid").hide("explode",1000);
   $( this ).fadeIn(100);
});
```